# update manytomany related field while an instance been created in django

Tags: django, django-signals, manytomanyfield

i want to to update a field related to M2M whenever an instance of `MobileCustomer` been created i tried signals but it seems complicate to `ManyToManyField` , i want to update `active` from `active=True` to `active=False` field in `Imei` model

i tried these ways but non of them worked in my case , i appreciate your helps

```
def mobile_customer(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
if created:

     for status in instance.imei.all():
         Imei.objects.filter(pk=status.id).update(active=False)

post_save.connect(mobile_customer,sender=SelectMobile)
```

and also this in my `CreateView` class views.py

```
Imei.objects.filter(selectmobile__item=self.object).update(active=False)
```

even if i try to print `Imei.objects.filter(selectmobile__item=self.object).update(active=False)` the output will be 0 !

this is my model design

```
class MobileCustomer(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    mobile = models.ManyToManyField(MobileStorage,through='SelectMobile')

class SelectMobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MobileCustomer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    imei = models.ManyToManyField(Imei)

class MobileStorage(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile_name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

i appreciate your helps ..
thanks

Comment: could you please name the field you want to update and the instance model? you don't have any `SelectMobileCustomer` in your models.

Comment: i  updated the question